# How to sign android app bundle with private-key.pepk file?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have a app which is already published in Google play. I want to publish upgraded version.

I have private-key.pepk and also my app is enabled with "Google app signing", but I dont have old keystore.

How can I publish my new version with same package?

Comment: Without the old keystore and password you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the application without old keystore. I would recommend that you update the play store page for your original application and link it to your new one same application so that you can keep some of your existing users.Make sure to make it clear in both the title and description that the application is outdated and not being updated.Delete the old one after you feel like you've rebuild your user base.

Comment: But I have google app signing enabled, and as per the documentation, they claim if you loose keystore, this feature can help us to retrieve the same, I am just not aware how to retrieve it

Comment: Did you get any help on this?